# Rails: Can't build object wth Factory Girl after adding accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I cannot get Factory Girl to produce a User object when accepts_nested_attributes_for is enabled.

Given the models:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :meta, polymorphic: true, dependent: :destroy
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :account, as: :meta
  validates :fname, presence: true
  validates :lname, presence: true
  validates_presence_of :account
  #accepts_nested_attributes_for :account
end
```

And, the factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do   
  factory :account do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "account#{n}@mack.com" }
    password "abcdef123"
    password_confirmation "abcdef123"
    confirmed_at Date.today   
  end 
end

FactoryGirl.define do   
  factory :user do
    sequence(:fname) { |n| "first#{n}" }
    sequence(:lname) { |n| "last#{n}" }
    after(:build) do |user|
      user.build_account attributes_for(:account)
    end   
  end 
end
```

The following spec:

```
describe User, :type => :model do

  it "has a valid factory" do
    user = build(:user)
    expect(user).to be_valid
  end
end
```

Fails if I uncomment the accepts_nested_attributes_for in the User model. I  would like to use the nested attributes for working with User objects, but I cannot figure out how to get FactorGirl to build a User with nested attributes enabled.

I get the following error:

```
  1) User has a valid factory
     Failure/Error: expect(user).to be_valid
       expected #<User id: nil, fname: "first1", lname: "last1", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> \
to be valid, but got errors: Account meta must exist
```

I am using Rails version 5.0.0beta1 and Factory Girl 4.6.0.

I've been battling this all day -- thanks for your help.

Edit: I see the same behavior using the rails console, so it would seem like the issue is independent of Factory Girl.